# run a vba macro in a workbook from another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a **macroB** in **WorkbookB** which opens another **WorkbookA** and runs **macroA** in sheet1.

I googled and found two methods:

- Using `Application.Run`

  ```
  Dim i As Integer, en As Integer
  en = Range("B4")

  Application.Run "C\Mtest\WorkbookA.xlsb !macroA"
  ```

  But I get the error 1004: either the macro dose not exist in this sheet or the macro  is deactivate
- Using `RunAutoMacros`

  ```
  Workbooks.Open "C\Mtest\WorkbookA.xlsb"
  Workbooks("WorkbookA.xlsb").Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
  ActiveWorkbook.RunAutoMacros macroA
  ```

  And here I get the error: 1004 the method RunAutoMacros does not work.

Any idea what is wrong? Or how can I do it in a better way?

Comment: Easiest way is to add a macro to you XLSTART file so it is attached to all opened Excel instances (saved as .xla or .xlam).  File location should be %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART for WIn7 and newer.  I personally tend to make quick ribbon buttons attached to the macro I want, if I run it often enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `macroA` is in the code module of `sheet1` of workbook `C\Mtest\WorkbookA.xlsb`, you should use

```
Application.Run "'C\Mtest\WorkbookA.xlsb'!sheet1.macroA"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the space is the problem.  Try removing it.  i.e. - change this line

```
Application.Run "C\Mtest\WorkbookA.xlsb !macroA"
```

to

```
Application.Run "C\Mtest\WorkbookA.xlsb!macroA"
```